# Mumble crashes on connection

Tags: windows-vista, crash, mumble

I'm trying to get Mumble connected to a server, but when I do, it crashes. It just shuts down and when you hover over the icon in the taskbar it disappears. The machine it's running on is Windows Vista x64 Ultimate with no firewalls. Nothing in their docs addresses this, and I"m not sure what else to try.

Any suggestions?